# Python socketio add namespace after a connection is started

Tags: python, socket.io, namespaces, connection

Looking at the python socketio documentation I defined a custom namespace:

```
import socketio


class MyCustomNamespace(socketio.ClientNamespace):

    def on_connect(self):
        pass

    def on_disconnect(self):
        pass

    def on_my_event(self, data):
        self.emit('my_response', data)

sio = socketio.Client()
sio.register_namespace(MyCustomNamespace('/chat'))
sio.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8888")
sio.emit("get", namespace="/chat")
```

Now this namespace works as long as I start the connection after registering the namespace. Makes sense.
But is there a way to register namespaces after the connection has started? I get the following error:

```
  File "//src/pipeline/reporting/iam.py", line 30, in request_iam_credentials
    self.socket_client.emit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 393, in emit
    raise exceptions.BadNamespaceError(
socketio.exceptions.BadNamespaceError: /chat is not a connected namespace.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each namespace is kinda different space you have to **connect** to. If you don't use the namespace explicitely it's defaulted to '/'. Look:

```
sio = socketio.Client()
sio.emit("get") # emit before connect

# socketio.exceptions.BadNamespaceError: / is not a connected namespace.
```

Your situation is the same, but with `/chat` namespace - you connect to `/` but try emiting to `/chat`. You need to connect to `/chat` namespace by yourself:

```
sio.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8888", namespaces=["/chat"]) # notice you can connect to more namespaces at once
```

which is exactly what `sio.connect` do when you register namespace earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but I get the error `socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Already connected` if I have already connected to the default namespace `/`

Comment: You cannot perform connect on client that is already connected. Connect to all namespaces at once, perform disconnect first or create new `socketio.Client`

Comment: This last comment is actually the answer that I needed. Thanks!